# Teams Graph Calls API, how make a Consultative Transfer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I can make a call from a BOT to a teams user, and can carry out a "blind" transfer of that call to another teams user using

```
   public async Task TransferCallAsync(string replaceCallId, string userDisplayName, string userID)
        {
           
            var transferTarget = new InvitationParticipantInfo
                {
                    Identity = new IdentitySet
                    {
                        User = new Identity
                        {
                            DisplayName = userDisplayName,
                            Id = userID
                        }
                    },
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                         {
                            {"endpointType", "default"}
                         },
                };
           
                    await graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls[replaceCallId]
                        .Transfer(transferTarget)
                        .Request()
                        .PostAsync();
             }
```

derived from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Chttp#request

In order to carry out a "consultative transfer" (traditionally this means that the Party A is put on hold whilst the operator/BOT dials the Party B, speaks to the Party B, then actions the transfer of Party A to Party B and drops out of the call), the documentation at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Chttp#request-1

shows that I need to use the same code as for a blind transfer, but add a

```
"ReplacesCallId = "..some Call ID.."
```

to the `transferTarget` structure.

My question is, where does this ID come from ?

Note that this is not the id of the call which exists between the BOT and party A. This gives a "Code: 8523 Message: replacesCallId matches callId. Cannot replace a call with itself"

What API steps are necessary to generate the ReplacesCallId value.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitationparticipantinfo?view=graph-rest-1.0
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does the target need to be in a call ?  If they are not in a call, how should a consultative transfer be done ?

Comment: Could you please check this sample for reference and try this out.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp

Comment: Thank you.  I managed to carry out a consultative transfer using the API.  However whilst it does transfer it does not necessarily do what is needed for a consultative transfer.  The BOT would need to be able to be in one call with party A, then put them on hold and dial or invite party B before speaking to partyB only, and then transferring.  As I said the transfer bit works but the interaction with each party does not seem possible.  In that respect it is not very different to transferring to partyB when it is not in a call (Blind Transfer) which does work.